# Generate time series sequence from dataframe without unique index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe coming from a csv which has the following columns:
user_id, path, timestamp, gender

```
| user_id   | path  | timestamp             | gender    |
|:-------:  |------ |---------------------  |--------   |
| 0         | 1     | 2017-01-01 01:08:56   | f         |
| 0         | 2     | 2017-01-01 01:07:56   | f         |
| 0         | 3     | 2017-01-01 01:08:40   | f         |
| 0         | 4     | 2017-01-01 01:04:36   | f         |
| 0         | 5     | 2017-01-01 01:09:53   | f         |
| 0         | 6     | 2017-01-01 01:12:33   | f         |
| 0         | 7     | 2017-01-01 01:14:12   | f         |
| 0         | 8     | 2017-01-01 01:16:25   | f         |
| 0         | 9     | 2017-01-01 01:16:56   | f         |
| 1         | 1     | 2017-01-01 01:08:56   | m         |
| 1         | 2     | 2017-01-01 01:08:06   | m         |
| 1         | 3     | 2017-01-01 01:10:51   | m         |
| 1         | 4     | 2017-01-01 01:13:53   | m         |
| 2         | 1     | 2017-01-01 01:08:56   | f         |
| 3         | 2     | 2017-01-01 01:34:56   | m         |
```

The output should be like this a sequence of elements:

```
| paths                 | timestamps                                                                                                                                                                                    | gender    |
|-------------------    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  |--------   |
| 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9     | 2017-01-01 01:08:56, 2017-01-01 01:07:56, 2017-01-01 01:08:40, 2017-01-01 01:04:36, 2017-01-01 01:09:53, 2017-01-01 01:12:33, 2017-01-01 01:14:12, 2017-01-01 01:16:25, 2017-01-01 01:16:56   | f         |
```

The problem is there are multiple rows to the same user_id from different timestamps and I need a sequence from that for time series classification (predicting gender based on path). Additionally the timestamps aren't unique through the whole dataframe, but they are for each user.

I tried first with pandas groupby function with the following code

```
dictionary = {}

for name, group in grouped:
   index = name[0]
   if dictionary.get(index, -1) == -1:
       dictionary[index] = {"sequence": group.path.values, "timestamps": group.timestamp.values, "gender": group.gender.values[0]}
   else:
       dictionary[index]["sequence"] = [dictionary[index]["sequence"], group.path.values]
```

this doesn't really work as I can't get the values out (it stays multi indexed) and I am unable to extract the values from each group.

Additionally i tried it with the following code snippet:

```
dictionary = {}

for name, group in grouped:
    index = name[0]
    if dictionary.get(index, -1) == -1:
        dictionary[index] = {"sequence": group.path.values, "timestamps": group.timestamp.values, "gender": group.gender.values[0]}
    else:
        dictionary[index]["sequence"] = [dictionary[index]["sequence"], group.path.values]
```

[image: Result after trying to generate a dictionary]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i assume there is a database involved? if so see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't mentioned it @RaymondNijland the data comes from a csv

Comment: You should describe what you're trying to do. The best way would be to also include an expected output

Comment: @Erfan thanks for the feedback! I've added an expected output